# Set up On-premise ADFS (4.0 Windows Sever 2016) to Net Core API

Tags: authorization, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1, adfs4.0

I am looking foward a way on how can I authorize my net core API 2.1 to an on premise ADFS. Most of the documentation and tutorials are set up with the azure AD and JWT Token Bearer but not with ADFS.

Comment: Maybe this helps - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your help. But we need to autorize a background job that make request to several API´s and there are no user further than the user that starts the app pool in our on-premise IIS. So this authetication must be set as "automatic" We have reach this approach with a web application, not with a backgroud job.